# autofac and webapi 2 ModelBinder called twice - second time with an empty bindingContext.ModelName

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac, imodelbinder

**I have the following configuration:**

```
builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();
RegisterModelBinder<TypeModelBinder, object>(config, builder).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

**Which uses the following method:**

```
private static IRegistrationBuilder<TBinder, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle> RegisterModelBinder<TBinder, TTarget>(HttpConfiguration config, ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    var targetType = typeof(TTarget);
    var regBuilder = builder.RegisterType<TBinder>()
        .WithParameter("validateAllProperties", true)
        .AsModelBinderForTypes(targetType);
    config.ParameterBindingRules.Add(targetType, p => p.BindWithModelBinding());
    return regBuilder;
}
```

I haven't marked up my controllers in any way.

**But the an example of the signature is:**

```
[Route("data/{type}")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(string type, object data)
```

**The binder:**

```
public class TypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public TypeModelBinder(ITypeResolver resolver, ITypeSerializer serializer, IContextETagExtractor eTagExtractor, bool validateAllProperties)
        : base(resolver, serializer, eTagExtractor, validateAllProperties)
    {
    }

    public override bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var typeInfo = default(RuntimeTypeInfo);
        var data = default(T);
        try
        {
            typeInfo = Resolver.Resolve(typeof(T).Name);
            data = this.BindData(actionContext);

            Validate(typeInfo.Type, data, bindingContext);
            if (this.IsConcurrentMethod(actionContext.Request.Method) && typeInfo.IsVersioned)
            {
                ValidateAndSetConcurrencyToken(typeInfo.Type, data, actionContext, bindingContext);
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ae)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Body", ae.Message);
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException jse)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Body", jse.Message);
        }
        catch (FormatException fe)
        {
            var errMsg = string.Format("{0} {1}", Constants.MODEL_ERROR_PREFIX_IF_MATCH_INVALID, fe.Message);
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(Constants.MODEL_ERROR_KEY_IF_MATCH, errMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Body", e.Message);
        }

        bindingContext.Model = data;
        return bindingContext.ModelState.IsValid;
    }
}
```

I have written a test to check that when I pass up an invalid object the model binding in the `TypeModelBinder` fails.

However I have noticed the following behaviour. The first time through it acts as I expect and `bindingContext.ModelName` is set to `"data"`

However I have noticed that when binding fails it immediately re-enters the the BindModel method of the binder, this time with `bindingContext.ModelName` set to `""` it then adds another copy of whichever model error has been added and something in the owin stack throws a 500...

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong when wiring up my modelbinders?